# How to sort,uniq and display line that appear more than X times

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I have a file like this:

```
80.13.178.2
80.13.178.2
80.13.178.2
80.13.178.2
80.13.178.1
80.13.178.3
80.13.178.3
80.13.178.3
80.13.178.4
80.13.178.4
80.13.178.7
```

I need to display unique entries for repeated line (similar to uniq -d) but only entries that occur *more* than just twice (twice being an example so flexibility to define the lower limit.)

Output for this example should be like this when looking for entries with three or more occurrences:

```
80.13.178.2
80.13.178.3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With pure `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > 2){print i}}}' a.txt
```

It iterates over the file and counts the occurances of every IP. At the end of the file it outputs every IP which occurs more than 2 times.

Comment: @Kent Thanks to Bell Labs! :)

Answer (score 24):

Feed the output from `uniq -cd` to `awk`

```
sort test.file | uniq -cd | awk -v limit=2 '$1 > limit{print $2}'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, this one works for me: cat log.txt | sort | uniq -d -c|awk '$1 > 30{print $2}'

Comment: This is a much cleaner, simpler solution.. Thank you