# How to sort,uniq and display line that appear more than X times using a variable search

Tags: awk

What would be the proper way to change the "2" limit to use a variable? I have a file of IP addresses that I want to report only the addresses with a count over the max variable.

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > **2**){print i}}}' a.txt
```

Attempt 1:

```
max=5
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > max){print i}}}' a.txt
```

Attempt 2:

```
$max, max {max}
```

Thanks

Question is based on this link:

[Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147878/how-to-sort-uniq-and-display-line-that-appear-more-than-x-times?newreg=67b23722d94743d48e149713f96b10fa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147878/how-to-sort-uniq-and-display-line-that-appear-more-than-x-times?newreg=67b23722d94743d48e149713f96b10fa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maxInShell=5
awk -v maxInAwk="$maxInShell" '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > maxInAwk){print i}}}' a.txt
```

used lengthy var-name to save explanations.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v max=5 '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > max){print i}}}' a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `awk` script is part of another shell script who creates the variable `max`, then you can use that variable in `awk` script by using `-v` option of `awk`.

For example:

```
awk -v max="$max" '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > max){print i}}}' a.txt
```